# How do you query postgres arrays in ruby on rails for integers using a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Notification.where("uip  @> ?", '{1}')
```

Works fine and returns all the notifications whose uip array contain a 1.

If I try the following with a variable, however, I have no such luck:

```
ip = 1

Notification.where("uip  @> ?", '{ip}')
```

Return the error:

```
Notification Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> '{ip}')
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "ip"
LINE 1: ...otifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> '{ip}')
                                                                ^
: SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> '{ip}')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "ip"
LINE 1: ...otifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> '{ip}')
                                                                ^
: SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> '{ip}')
```

And another attempt with:

```
Notification.where("uip  @> ?", ip)
```

Gives the error:

```
SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> 1)
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint[] @> integer
LINE 1: ...CT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> 1)
                                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint[] @> integer
LINE 1: ...CT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> 1)
                                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications"  WHERE (uip  @> 1)
```

So how can I simply find objects by an integer variable inside a postgres array in rails?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `Notification.where("uip  @> ?", '{ip}')` try `Notification.where("uip  @> ?", '{' + ip + '}')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can query in a postgres array using ActiveRecord:

Fixing your query:

```
ip = 1    
Notification.where("uip @> '{?}'", ip)
```

Using 'ANY':

```
ip = 1
Notification.where("uip && ARRAY[?]", ip)
```

Comment: First one works thanks :), second doesn't seem to: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint[] && integer[]`

Comment: I would suggest you to go with @> as you can index it with gin.

Comment: First one doesn`t seems to work with string arrays, but second one does

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an array from your input:

```
Notification.where("uip @> CAST(ARRAY[?] AS BIGINT[])", ip)
// or
Notification.where("uip @> CAST(? AS BIGINT[])", '{' + ip.to_s + '}')
// or
Notification.where("uip @> CAST('{' || ? || '}' AS BIGINT[])", ip)
```

If you want to test only one element, you can use the overlap (`&&`) operator too (which should be faster, a little). Or, you can use the `ANY` construct for arrays:

```
Notification.where("? = ANY (uip)", ip)
```

Comment: 3rd and 4th work thanks :), the first two render errors: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint[] @> integer[]` and `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` respectively

Comment: Would an ANY be faster than @> ?

Comment: @Laser then you need exeplicit casts everywhere; `ANY` is just simpler & works decent with smaller sets, but not indexable. The `@>` and `&&` operators are indexable with [`gin`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I just moved your braces into condition:

```
ip = 1
Notification.where("uip  @> '{?}'", ip)
```

Comment: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"`

Answer (score 0):

Use it. i think this is helpful for you

```
ip = 1 
Notification.where("uip  @> ?", "#{ip.to_s.to_i}")
```

OR

```
Notification.where("uip @>?",ip.to_s.to_i)
```

Comment: `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "1"`

Comment: Hi laser, I have changed my answer now.. You use this method.. I think it will be helpful for you